# Raising an exception: use instance or class?

Tags: ruby, exception

I have seen Ruby code that raises exceptions using a class:

```
raise GoatException,    "Maximum of 3 goats per bumper car."
```

Other code uses an instance:

```
raise GoatException.new "No leotard found suitable for goat."
```

Both of these are rescued the same way. Is there any reason to use an instance vs a class?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It makes no difference; the exception class will be instiantiated in either case.

If you provide a string, either as the argument to `new` or as the second argument to `raise`, it be passed to `initialize` and will become the exception instance's `.message`.

For example:

```
class GoatException < StandardError
  def initialize(message)
    puts "initializing with message: #{message}"
    super
  end
end

begin
  raise GoatException.new "Goats do not enjoy origami." #--|
                                                        #  | Equivilents
  raise GoatException,    "Goats do not enjoy origami." #--|
rescue Exception => e
  puts "Goat exception! The class is '#{e.class}'. Message is '#{e.message}'"
end
```

If you comment the first `raise` above, you'll see that:

- In both cases, `initialize` is called.
- In both cases, the exception class is `GoatException`, not `class` as it would be if we were rescuing the exception class itself.